# awk if else condition not working

Tags: awk

I need to add the value 0.0 at the 3rd column in csv file for all lines that I am able to add that using the following command.

```
awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=',' '{$2=$2",0.0"} 1' test.csv
```

However, when i am checking if the 3rd column exist in the line then only add the value using following command is not working.

```
awk -F, '{ if (length($2) != 0)  `awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=',' '{$2=$2",0.0"} 1'` ;}' test.csv
```

test.csv

```
2016-10-25 11:18:42.945 UTC,"dummy",546

2016-10-25 11:18:42.950 UTC

set misc_data = 'La Carmela de Boracay Resort Hotel|Twin 
Deluxe|Breakfast|AC|NA|Triple Sharing|-1_U_Miss_NINIA_HANNAH_FUGUIAO_-1_Non_false_#|'

1,2,5
3
```

OUTPUT:

```
2016-10-25 11:18:42.945 UTC,"dummy",0.0,546

1,2,0.0,5
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need an explicit `if` test - you can incorporate the logic into an awk *pattern*

```
awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=',' 'NF>1 && length($2) !=0 {$2=$2",0.0"; print}' test.csv
2016-10-25 11:18:42.945 UTC,"dummy",0.0,546
1,2,0.0,5
```

If you want to use `if`, the syntax is `if (condition) {expression}` e.g.

```
awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=',' 'NF>1 {if (length($2) !=0) {$2=$2",0.0"; print}}' test.csv
```

Comment: That works !! 
and what changes required if i need the following output: All rows should come however, if 3rd column has value then it should add value 0.0 

2016-10-25 11:18:42.945 UTC,"dummy",0.0,546
2016-10-25 11:18:42.950 UTC
set misc_data = 'La Carmela de Boracay Resort Hotel|Twin 
Deluxe|Breakfast|AC|NA|Triple Sharing|-1_U_Miss_NINIA_HANNAH_FUGUIAO_-1_Non_false_#|'
1,2,0.0,5
3

Comment: @dhaval if you want to print all lines, move the `print` statement outside of the action for the `NF>1 && length($2) !=0` rule.

Comment: awk -v FS=',' -v OFS=',' 'NF>1 {if (length($2) !=0) {$2=$2",0.0"} print;}' test.csv gives me same result only. Where im doing mistake

Comment: `'NF>1 && length($2) !=0 {$2=$2",0.0";} {print}'` so the `{print}` action is applied to every line. Or just `'NF>1 && length($2) !=0 {$2=$2",0.0";} 1'` for brevity since `print` is the default action.